# What is the best way to identify a requests call origin to a REST API

Tags: android, ios, rest

I've got an API which takes requests from a website, android devices and ios devices.
Now, I've got to store in the entities which are created in the API calls where they were created from.
So, for instance, if the user created a new entity from his android app, i should also store in that entity that information.
My question is how should I implement that on the API. I have though of 3 ways to do that:

1 - Make the api user send that new field on the body of the request. 
I dont like this aproach because the data being sent is not actualy refered to the entity created, it's more like meta information.

2 - Make the api user send a new header, for instance "X-Origin: android"
I don't like this one because I'm not keen of the idea of creating a new header just for that information when I could just use the User-Agent header.

3 - Use the User-Agent Header
This is the one I'm tending torwards to, but can I really trust this? So many android devices with so many diferent headers.
In the android app, I'm using Apache's HTTP client, so the header it sends is

`'User-Agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)'`

Although I can retrieve with System.getProperty("http.agent") the "correct" header, which for my phone is:

`"Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; Nexus 4 Build/JWR66Y)"`

This information is not required, so not suplying it will not change the way the API behaves. The entity will still be created, but without the extra info.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't see a problem with either 1 or 2.  3 I would avoid for the reasons you list, plus it's a moving target.

Comment: I ended up going with the custom header solution, seems the cleanest way. Thanks.